# Have a 2.5gbps LAN but ethernet speed only shows 1000Mb/s? Ubuntu 20.04, MSI motherboard

Tags: networking, ubuntu, drivers, motherboard, ethernet

I am having a MSI Z590 PRO WIFI motherboard which claims to have 2.5Gbps LAN. However, when I connect to ethernet cable (CAT8). I only have 1000Mbs. Why is this happening?

The current network setup is that:

For both modem to router and router directly to my computer, I use cat8 ethernet cables. My router can send 5GHz WIFI which has speed 2200Mbit/s. I use my laptop to receive the WIFI and the rate goes to 1053Mbps.

I am also thinking about the Linux kernel network/ethernet interface driver. But I am not sure how to update/modify.

Here is some input/output…

Type in:

`lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

Get:

```bash
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15f3] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7d09]
    Kernel driver in use: igc
    Kernel modules: igc
```

Type in:

`ethtool enp2s0`

Get:

```
Settings for enp2s0:
    Supported ports: [ ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
                            2500baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
                            2500baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off (auto)
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

Type in:

`sudo lshw -C network`

Get:

```bash
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 03
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=5.10.0-1023-oem duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
```

Comment: With technology, you only get the speed of your slowest link in the chain. So the MOBO has 2.5Gb LAN, and the Ethernet cable may be good for 40Gb. What is the cable plugged into? Is it a Gigabit switch? Is the router Gigabit? Every single piece of equipment between the two networked computers needs to be at least 2.5Gb/s. What is your networking setup?

Comment: @coltmorgan Thank you for the help. For both modem to router and router directly to my computer, I use cat8 ethernet cables. My router can send 5GHz WIFI which has speed 2200Mbit/s. I am not quite sure how to check whether this router is Gigabit. Internet provider is Spectrum. Should I also buy a switch, Gigabit switch in particular, between modem and router?

Comment: @coltmorgan I found that my router is  RAC2V1S from spectrum and from the official website I found that 
IEEE 802.3 Ethernet: 10-BASE-T, 100-BASE-T, 1000-Speed BASE-T. Is that mean that the router can have Ethernet port speed of at most 1000Mbps?

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding of the speeds here... Your link to your PC is 1GB/s and that will be faster than your "1053Mbps" connection via WiFi  to your laptop for a variety of reasons, the most important being WiFi is half-duplex and a one at a time protocol, and your WiFI speeds will vary, significantly, with normal use. You don't see a 2500Mbps connection because whatever you plugging it into doesn't have 2.,5Gb Ethernet ports. The issues is even if it did would you benefit from it? Not unless your Internet is in excess of 1.5Gbps down which is incredibly unlikely.

Comment: Yes, the Sagecom Fast 5280 Router (RAC2V1S) only has 1000Mbps maximum Ethernet ports. Which is still faster than your WiFi...

Comment: The main issue with 2.5 Gigabit LAN is the difficulty with getting above 1 Gigabit networking equipment. Even 2.5 GB/s is expensive, probably because it is considered "enterprise grade." The only real benefit to having 2.5 Gb/s in your home would be if you had a NAS or some such and were moving files around, large files. The fact is most people do not need greater than 1 Gb/s networking, or even know what those words mean, or even care. So there really is no need for it in the consumer space, hence the difficulty with getting the proper equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet link speed is determined by *Autonegotiation*: both sides advertise their speeds and capabilities and the best mutual mode is chosen.

Accordingly, a NIC with 2.5G capability (2.5GBASE-T) and a switch port with 1G capability (1000BASE-T) link with 1 Gbit/s. Very likely, your Wi-Fi router only supports 1000BASE-T. The wireless speeds it supports are irrelevant.

Comment: The speed will also be limited by the processor on the modem, as you point out, the modem probably doesn’t have a 2.5G LAN port.

Comment: The *effective* speed may be limited by various parameters. The *link* speed is only determined by mutual port capabilities (and the cable grade for 2.5GBASE-T and 5GBASE-T only).

Answer (score -2):

With technology, you only get the speed of your slowest link in the chain. So the MOBO has 2.5Gb LAN, and the Ethernet cable may be good for 40Gb. What is the cable plugged into? Is it a Gigabit switch? Is the router Gigabit? Every single piece of equipment between the two networked computers needs to be at least 2.5Gb/s.

The only real reason that you would need 2.5Gb/s LAN in your home would be if you had network storage device like a NAS, and needed to consistently move around large files. Keep in mind the 2.5Gb/s is about 300 megabytes per second, so if you are moving files in excess of 10 Gigabytes on a regular basis, and your time is very important, it may be worth the investment to upgrade.

Couple of things to keep in mind here; First, 300 MB/s easily outstrips the read and write speed of a single Hard drive, and even some low end SSDs. So if you are using a NAS or a storage server, you would need at least 5 HDDs striped together in order to get the performance benefit of 2.5Gb/s LAN.
Second, consumer networking equipment only goes up to gigabit, so if you do decide to upgrade it will need to be commercial grade equipment. This means much more expensive.